# typecript compiler API, checker, getTypeCatalog? Is there a declared types table availble from checker of why not?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

After intialize the typescript compiler API like this ...

```
 const program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, options);
 const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
```

the program is now compiled, meaning the typescript program has gone through the entire program once, and has had a chance to build a types table.

In the debug version of typescript available on github, there is function on checker ...

```
ts.getTypeChecker().getTypeCatalog()
```

but on the release version it is not available.

To quote from the [limited documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview), which describes at the conceptual level only, without examples:

> Symbol: A named declaration. Symbols are created as a result of binding. Symbols connect declaration nodes in the tree to other declarations contributing to the same entity. Symbols are the basic building block of the semantic system.
> Type: Types are the other part of the semantic system. Types can be named (e.g. classes and interfaces), or anonymous (e.g. object types).
>
> The first thing a TypeChecker will do is to consolidate all the Symbols from different SourceFiles into a single view, and build a single Symbol Table by "merging" any common Symbols (e.g. namespaces spanning multiple files).
>
> After initializing the original state, the TypeChecker is ready to answer any questions about the program. Such "questions" might be:
>
> What is the Symbol for this Node?
> What is the Type of this Symbol?
> What Symbols are visible in this portion of the AST?
> What are the available Signatures for a function declaration?
> What errors should be reported for a file?
>
> The TypeChecker computes everything lazily; it only "resolves" the necessary information to answer a question. The checker will only examine Nodes/Symbols/Types that contribute to the question at hand and will not attempt to examine additional entities.

So to answer my own question: yes and no.

Yes, because *"TypeChecker will ... consolidate all the Symbols from different SourceFiles into a single view"*.

No because *"The TypeChecker computes everything lazily; it only "resolves" the necessary information to answer a question."*

There are several dozens of function available on `ts.getTypeChecker()` - they are undocumented and in [the examples](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) there are no usage examples for the case of resolving "deep" types.

I have successfully used `ts.getTypeChecker.forEachChild(...)` to traverse a file and, e.g., locate function declarations.  But with type in hand, I do not know how to use the checker to resovle the type and create a hierarchy down to primitives.

Comment: Is this in the docs anywhere?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights - I've expanded the question in response to your comment.

Comment: I still can't find any reference to `getTypeCatalog`.

Comment: It does say [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API), "Keep in mind that this is not yet a stable API...".

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look for this information is through the [TypeScript compiler's source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript).

The `getTypeCatalog` function is internal and not part of the public API ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e4c4292807f10b093aaffa9dfabdf6fbe22c6ffd/src/compiler/types.ts#L4184)):

```
interface TypeChecker {
  // ...omitted...

  /* @internal */ getTypeCatalog(): readonly Type[];

  // ...omitted...
}
```

I'm not sure having access to it is that useful though.

> I have successfully used ts.getTypeChecker.forEach(...) to traverse a file and, e.g., locate function declarations. But with type in hand, I do not know how to use the checker to resovle the type and create a hierarchy down to primitives.

I don't think a `forEach` function exists on `TypeChecker` (perhaps you meant the `forEach` on a symbol?).

To do this, you can get the source file ASTs (`program.getSourceFiles()`), traverse them using `sourceFile.forEachChild(child => { /* call child.forEachChild recursively */ })`, then you can use `typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(child)` to get the types.

Comment: I have changed `forEach` to `forEachChild`.  Obviously, I wouldn't have iterated the tree without using `forEachChild`.  `getTypeAtLocation` returns the type of an identifier, which doesn't answer my question.  "Read the code" - yes, but that's the default anyway.

Comment: @CraigHicks `forEachChild` is avialable on either `Node` or the exported `ts` module (not on TypeChecker). Sorry, some people may traverse the symbols and not the AST, so it's not so obvious... especially when discussing `forEach`, which is a symbol method. To put my answer in other words, I don't believe it's possible to get this via the public API. Probably traversing the declarations and using `getTypeAtLocation` is your best bet (or perhaps using `getSymbolAtLocation` and `getSymbolsInScope` depending on your situation). Using `Type#getBaseTypes` and `Type#getProperties()` might be useful.

Comment: getSymbolsInScope is producing useful results.